# How to get rid of b9g.ru iframe injected on to a website

Tags: malware, malware-detection

I have done a website whose URL is http://www.netbramha.com

Unfortunately after the end of each page, I have the following piece getting added

```
<iframe src="" width=186 height=182 style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

The src is from b9g.ru.

I have gone through all the required files and none of them have these and there in no entry of this in the database as well.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Your site has been hacked. It will help to post information about the implementation technology (PHP ?) and the hosting method (shared hosting, private server).

Comment: its on php and its shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

It's a virus, perhaps from a wordpress plugin you installed. Check your computer for a virus.

**Update**:

Try to ask your hosting provider for help. It might be their problem. Otherwise, try to grep for b9g in sources, something like "`grep -r -i b9g ./`", although it's probably encripted.

Comment: i have used twiiter-for-wordpress and wp-syntax

Could this virus be removed or does the site have to be remade from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

If its wordpress, try having a look in the comments, and try disabling all of your plugins, and check the content they add one by one to see what its doing. Other things you can check after that is to try switching the template to one freshly downloaded from the WP site.